# Determining whether certain words are singular or plural

Tags: hebrew, daniel

Regarding the Daniel 8:26 verse, is the evening and morning in singular or in plural, in the original Hebrew? If you could attach evidence, that would be appreciated immensely.

Answer (score 2):

> וּמַרְאֵה **הָעֶרֶב וְהַבֹּקֶר** אֲשֶׁר נֶאֱמַר אֱמֶת הוּא וְאַתָּה סְתֹם הֶחָזוֹן כִּי לְיָמִים רַבִּים
> *umarʾeh **ha-ʿerev veha-boker** asher neʾemar emet hu veʾatta setom hechazon ki leyamim rabbim*

הָעֶרֶב (*ha-ʿerev*), “the evening”, and וְהַבֹּקֶר (*veha-boker*), “and the morning”, are declined in the singular number.

The plural number declension of עֶרֶב (*erev*) is עֲרָבִים (*aravim*).

Per Jastrow on עֶרֶב (*erev*),<sup>1</sup>

[image]

The plural number declension of בֹּקֶר (*boker*) is בְּקָרִים (*bekarim*).

Per Jastrow on בֹּקֶר (*boker*),<sup>2</sup>

[image]

---

| Footnotes |
| --- |
| <sup>1</sup> Jastrow, Vol. 2, p. [1111](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryoftarg02jastuoft/page/1110/mode/2up?view=theater) <sup>2</sup> Jastrow, Vol. 1, p. [187](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryoftarg01jastuoft/page/186/mode/2up?view=theater) |

| References |
| --- |
| Jastrow, Marcus. [*A Dictionary of the Targumim, the Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi, and the Midrashic Literature.*](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryoftarg01jastuoft) Vol. 1. London: Luzac; New York: Putnam, 1903. Jastrow, Marcus. [*A Dictionary of the Targumim, the Talmud Babli and Yerushalmi, and the Midrashic Literature.*](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryoftarg02jastuoft) Vol. 2. London: Luzac; New York: Putnam, 1903. |

Comment: It is a common misunderstanding that the Hebrew article ה- ha-/he- equals the English definite article "the".  e.g. היום ha-yom does not mean "the day", but it means the-this day = today. e.g. ha-satan in book of Eyuv/Job does not refer to "the singulr unique" satan , but to the-this satan among other satanim. People need to stop using English grammer to understand Hebrew or ancient Jewish Aramaic.

Comment: @Cynthia—People also need to avoid *non-sequiturs*.

Answer (score 1):

**Determining whether certain words are singular or plural:**

*Definition of "Singular":*
The singular form of a term refers to a single item, or a collection of items all of the same kind.

*Definition of "Plural":*
The plural form of a term refers to two or more of that item.

**Is the evening and morning in singular or in plural, in the original Hebrew?**

This is the relevant portion in [Hebrew](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/dan/8/26/t_concif_858026):

[image]

[image] [image]

You will notice that these two words are in the singular form in Hebrew. The singular form is used here to refer to the combined concept of "evening and morning" as a unit of time, representing a complete day.

Answer (score 1):

There is no question that the phrase in Dan 8:26 הָעֶ֧רֶב וְהַבֹּ֛קֶר = "of the evening and the morning", is declined in the singular.  See https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/8-26.htm  Exactly the same is true of the almost identical phrase in Dan 8:14.  See https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/8-14.htm

But here is the subtlety: the phrase "evening and morning" in V26 is a direct reference to that same (grammatically singular) phrase in V14 which is part of the longer phrase:

> "evening-morning two thousand and three hundred"

That is, we are told that there is 2300 of these "evening-morning" units - a direct reference to Genesis 1 where this phrase occurs regularly, denoting 24-hour days.

It is for all these reasons that almost all translators translate the V14 and V26 in the plural.  Daniel appears to emphasizing, by using the singular, that we have 2300 units of evening-morning, ie, days.  (I note that a few versions actually translate "days" such as KJV, NKJV, DRB, ISV, etc).

Note the almost subtle hint at this in V26 - "days" at the end of the the verse.